# regex + compilation boost?

Tags: c++, regex, windows, boost, mingw

2 There was a question: how to collect through MinGW boost? (OS: Windows)
And how to use regular expressions to cut the line?

Suppose there is a line: 192.168.1.1, I need to cut off the line after 2 bytes. It turns out:
Input: 192.168.1.1
Output: 192.168.*.*

Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for my clumsy English lang.

Comment: I probably would not use `regex` for this. Simple string manipulation would do it.

Comment: We need it through regex

Answer (score 0):

Althogh you shouldn't have needed regex for this but if you say regex is a must then you can try this:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.)\d+\.\d+
```

Sample Code:

```
string regx = R"((\d+\.\d+\.)\d+\.\d+)";
string input = "192.168.1.1";
smatch matches;
    if (regex_search(input, matches, regex(regx)))
    {
        cout<<matches[1]<<"."<<endl;
    }
```

[Execute it here](http://ideone.com/CjsU42)

Output:

```
192.168..
```